# Arduino & Dynamixel XM430-W210-R: Adding a potentiometer to increase/decrease rotation

Tags: arduino, dynamixel

I want to create an improvement to an Arduino script. I have a Dynamixel XM430-W210-R servo with a Dynamixel Shield and Arduino Mega. I am using the OP_EXTENDED_POSITION mode. Here is part of my code for 3 mechanical buttons:

```
  pinMode(switchPin1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(switchPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(switchPin3, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  int position1 = digitalRead(switchPin1);
  int position2 = digitalRead(switchPin2);
  int position3 = digitalRead(switchPin3);
  // Position 1
  if (position1 == HIGH && position2 == LOW && position3 == LOW) {
    dxl.setGoalPosition(DXL_ID, 2048);  // return to position zero
  }
  // Position 2
  else if (position1 == LOW && position2 == HIGH && position3 == LOW) {
    dxl.setGoalPosition(DXL_ID, 6143);  // one rotation
  }
  // Position 3
  else if (position1 == LOW && position2 == LOW && position3 == HIGH) {
    dxl.setGoalPosition(DXL_ID, 10238);   // two rotations
  }
  delay(100);  // delay to prevent bouncing 
}
```

I still would like to have the buttons move to their centre positions. Now, within Position 2 (1 rotation) and Position 3 (2 rotations) I have if statements, I need a potentiometer mapped to increase the Dynamixel motor by 2048 or decrease by 2048 based  on whether the potentiometer is turned clockwise (CW) or counter clockwise (CCW) from it’s starting centre position. Position 1 will not change. In this case, Position 2 is 6143 which will be the centre on the pot and can either decrease to 4095 or increase to 8190. Position 3 is centred at 10238 and can decrease to 8190 or increase to 12286. So, what I'm trying to say is the servo will follow the movement of the potentiometer. I tried to use the `movingAvg` library to store the average potentiometer value and compare it with the servo centre position. See this pseudo code:

```
if (average_Pot < Dynamixel_Position){
  SERVO = CLOCKWISE;
}
if ((average_Pot) == (Dynamixel_Position)){
  SERVO = CENTRE POSITION, DO NOTHING;
}
if (average_pot > Dynamixel_Position){
  SERVO = COUNTER-CLOCKWISE;
}

Dynamixel_Position = average_Pot;
```

I gave it a go and the Dynamixel motor isn’t moving and I’m not sure how to progress or if this is the best way to achieve what I’m after. First time I've really used one of these motors so not very familiar with it.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: it's simple,  don't use constant values in the first code ... add the potentiometer value to the settings

Comment: insert a layer of separation between the button code and the `dxl.setGoalPosition()` ... the button code sets a variable value only ... then use that value in `dxl.setGoalPosition()` after all the buttons are scanned ... that way you can adjust the value with the potentiometer in between

Comment: I have done it, thank you for the explanation, I have set a base position for each button position, then using setGoalPosition added the potentiometer position to whichever base position has been entered by the if statement. This way I can have the motor move to the desired position and then adjust that position by +-2048 using the map() function. Thanks